# Ruby on Rails: How to limit the key for Hash Fields in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

For example, I want to allow key `home_page` only for field `url`

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name
  field :url, type: Hash
end
```

I want this work

```
def set_vals
  self.first_name = 'Daniel'
  self.url = {'home_page' => 'http://www.homepage.com'}
  save
end
```

and this fail

```
def set_vals
  self.first_name = 'Daniel'
  self.url = {'unknown' => 'http://www.homepage.com'}
  save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a model validation, inspect the keys and add errors to the model if undesired keys are present.

Comment: How to do it in particular?